# How to create a static class from a nonstatic class

Tags: c#, class, oop

So I have a non static class

```
public class Client 
{
    private string _firstname, _lastname, _address;
    //Public constructors and Properties would go here//
}
```

I was wondering if there is anyway to make a static class out of this class which I can use to store the data of the current Client I am working with.

Comment: Put `static` as an access modifier.

Comment: Why would you want to make the class static?  Just create an instance of this class and work with that.  This way you can make a new instance when you are dealing with a different client

Comment: You could include a static field/property within the Client class which would hold the current Client instance you're working with. That said, global state such as this is generally a bad idea. Keep the Client you're working with confined to the code which is doing the work.

Comment: As TJ said just add `static`.  Your question isn't detailed enough.

Comment: That class looks like a poor candidate for a static class - will you really only ever have one `Client`? Never a `List<Client>`?

Comment: Fully agree with Rufus and maccettura. Leave the Client as is and use a static ClientStorage class or a service or whatever. But I'd recommend to leave the Client untouched as it is an entity, as you say had a _current_ client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, there's a couple of different ways to go here.

First, and most importantly: make sure that this is what you actually want to do.  If someone's connecting in to you and you're storing information about the client, you probably *want* a non-static instance of the class.  Something like:

```
public string OuterRequest(string someInput)
{
    Client requestor = new Client(); // Client instance for this request
    DoSomething(requestor);
    DoSomethingElse(requestor);
    return "Something";
}
```

... see what I'm getting at?  Someone generates a request, and you create a new instance of the Client class to store that info.  Anything that *needs* that data?  You pass the instance to them, so they can get info about the request/client.

Next up, if you're *positive* that you really want a single instance?

In that case, the next option is to do what's called a 'Singleton'.  Ultimately, you're looking for two building blocks to do this:

1. Private constructor
2. Public static property that's an instance of the class

So code-wise, you're looking at something like:

```
public class Client
{
    private Client() { } // private constructor

    public static Client instance = new Client();

    // usage:  Client.instance.WhateverPropertyYouWant;
}
```

You want this over just a plain static class.  Why?  Because, this way, you have the ability to create a unit test that spins up a *second* instance of the Client class to test functionality without messing up the properties/etc of the main/regular instance of the Client class.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the **Singleton** pattern. This pattern only allows a single instance of Client class to be created, and gives simple access to that instance.

To implement it use the following code:

*Note: You should also set the constructors of the class as **private**.*

```
public class Client 
{
    private static Client instance;

    public static Client Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                instance = new Client();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }

    string _firstname, _lastname, _address;
    //Public constructors and Properties would go here//
    // Make constructors Private! //
}
```

Now you are able to access (and implicitly create the instance) of your Client class using `Client.Instance`